# How to create a bool filter on multiple fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "travel_time": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['DateTo'].value - doc['DateFrom'].value"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "stored_fields": [
    "_source"
    ], 
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "DateTo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add `DateFrom` into `exists` filter?

Comment: which version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: @TobiasGassmann: 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple `exists` criteria:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [
       {
         "exists": {
           "field": "DateFrom"
         }
       },
       {
         "exists": {
           "field": "DateTo"
         }
       },
       {
         "script": {
           "script": {
             "inline": "doc['DateTo'].value - doc['DateFrom'].value > 0"
           }
         }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Can I also add the filter that `"doc['DateTo'].value - doc['DateFrom'].value"` should be a positive numeric value?